# set value to Cacheable annotation from property file

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

I'm using Spring Cacheable annotation and at the moment I'm struggling with a way of adding the cache name from property file.

I tried:

```
@Cacheable("${some.cache.name}")
```

and

```
@Cacheable("#{'${some.cache.name}'}")
```

Comment: And what kind of error/problem are you encountering?

Comment: From the docs I'd think SpEL is not supported in the `value`/`cacheNames` attribute of the `@Cacheable` annotation as (unlike the `key` attribute) nothing is stated regarding SpEL for `value`/`cacheNames`.  Describe why you want to read the cache name from a properties file. Maybe there is another way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I just want to keep the cache name in the property file. I cannot find a way to inject it.

Comment: This is understood. But **why**? Usually the name of a cache should be something that doesn't need to be configurable.

Comment: But I use the cache name twice in my code. When I define the cache itself and then when I use the `@Cacheable` annotation. This is why I came up with this question.

Comment: Simply define a constant `public static final String CACHE_NAME = "myCache"` somewhere in your code and reference the constant instead of reading it from the config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a SPI to do that that is much more powerful than just using SpEL. You can implement `CacheResolver` and resolve cache instance(s) at runtime. You could use the annotated type or any name that is provided via the annotation.

You can specify the `CacheResolver` per annotation, at class-level using `@CacheConfig` or globally by implementing  `CacheConfigurer`.

Check [the documentation for more details](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache-annotations-cacheable-cache-resolver)